# Defining some global GIT settings to be automatically inherited

Tags: terminal, macos, git

## Sysnopsis

Coming from a Linux background I still find Apples' modifications to the Unix hierarchy somewhat confusing.  Nevertheless these subtle changes make it difficult for me to quickly do what I need.

- I shall explain my scenario in a linux setting as it would make the most sense, then hope someone can translate this into BSD/OS X lingo.
- I do not like GUI-based things if theres a CLI alternative.

## Problem

I recently installed GIT so I could work on a number of projects from my MacBook, in linux one can define default config settings in `/etc/gitconfig` which is first loaded into the users' configuration and then merged with `~/.gitconfig`.

When I create this default global git configuration file inside `/etc/gitconfig` it has not effect when I run my aliases, unless I specifically define them for each user on the machine.

Could someone please suggest to me exactly how this default behaviour works on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone I found this config in the following location: `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
git config --system -e
```

and

```
git config --global -e
```

to open the system and global config files in an editor. That will tell you what path `git` is looking for those files, by looking at the file it opens.

Answer (score 0):

You won't believe it, but after installing Xcode 5.1.1 in Mavericks 10.9.3, now the `--system` path for my `gitconfig` is

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/etc/
```